# OctoPrint Unable to Connect to Lulzbot Mini

Tags: octoprint, lulzbot, serial-connection

We have a Lulzbot Mini at my office (i.e. it's not my personal printer). It's connected to an OctoPi and I've been able to get just one file to print on it (which I had to cancel due to leveling issues). Others have used it successfully in the past.

However, right now, every time I try to connect to it through OctoPrint, I just get gibberish back:

```
Connecting to: /dev/ttyACM0
Changing monitoring state from "Offline" to "Opening serial port"
Connected to: Serial<id=0x6f830510, open=True>(port='/dev/ttyACM0', baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=10.0, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False), starting monitor
Changing monitoring state from "Opening serial port" to "Connecting"
Send: N0 M110 N0*125
Send: N0 M110 N0*125
Recv: �Np|\x04n6H\x15\x06'
Recv: \x10ONv�HO
Recv: J%�i�h�ON,=\x0c\x14\x07�|i�Mx86B~1~\x04g\x1a\x1e�HO
Recv: J%P|H~\x03�^�-\x08n6�M�w��K�'
Recv: \x08�^�;V7JO\x1e\x0b�\x08\�H^�Kqp|\x08\x13\x08H\x08\x04P|"]+X{\x16�\x08nl�P<\x08\x14\x08]�x�
Recv: �J�X�\x1a�H3H6F�J�J%�J/H\x08^�I\x08ZY\x08\x07:&h\x0f^\x17�}�$p|\x08\x14
Recv: ^HJ�J�\x08�J\x1b�*':f\x18�k\x1e>H]�Zf�J�Z�J�%\x08^\x08W�X�\x1a�\x0b\x1e\x1eH]�Z�Kq?N!KP�.N!Kka�.a\x0b'
Recv: �J�J�JH�I�JHJP|@_a\x13�\x16�/m\x7f\x1fy�\x16=�6\x1b�VO6�=�6\x1b�f>�K7f\x7f�K{f>�K\x1bf��+'J�z�J\x08@�\x08�J%�\x18%�(�J\x17�
Recv: \x07
Recv: �M!
Recv: gJ�j�I�j\x08N�x�\x1a\x7fB
�\x0b]F�J�J�x�
Recv: V
Recv: o\x16�F�J�Z�j\x0c.�\x08%�\x05\x07J�j�5�\x18HJ�J�X�*�\F]{L$P<\x08�\x08~5Ip|\x04}&@\x1faF�J�J�If�\x1a33l\x7f�N\x0bYp|\x088
No answer from the printer within the connection timeout, trying another hello
Send: N0 M110 N0*125
There was a timeout while trying to connect to the printer
Changing monitoring state from "Connecting" to "Offline"
Connection closed, closing down monitor
```

The only thing I can think of right now is refreshing the firmware, but before I do that, I figured I'd ask here. Does any one know what this gibberish is and how I can restore this printer to regular operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the printer returns gibberish, the Baud rate of the connection is incorrect. You are using 115200 in the example above. For older Mini firmwares, it should indeed be 115200. For the newer 1.1.5.xx builds, it should be 250000.

Comment: Thanks! This turned out to be the issue with connecting to OctoPrint. I'm still having other issues with the printer, but that's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Feel free to post more questions! We welcome new content! Welcome to 3DPrinting.SE!